# Posting the form with jquery kit (jkit) validation via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am not sure why my ajax call is not working. I have a contact form with jkit validation enabled and I want to send it by AJAX once it passes all validation rules. Then I want to put the result into the html div instead of going to php. Please help

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="servercode/contact.php" data-jkit="[form:validateonly=yes; success=Your success message]">
    <div class="contact-one">
        <p>
            <label for="miniusername">Username:</label><br />
            <input name="miniusername" id="miniusername" data-jkit="[validate:required=true;min=3;max=10;error=Please enter your username (3-10  characters)]">
        </p>
    </div>  
    <div class="contact-two">  
        <p>
            <label for="miniemail">E-mail:</label><br />
            <input name="miniemail" id="miniemail" data-jkit="[validate:required=true;strength=50;error=Please write your email]">
        </p>
    </div>  
    <div class="contact-three">  
        <p>
            <label>Message:</label><br />
            <textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea><br/><br/> 
            <input class="button-submit" id="send" name="send" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
        </p>
    </div>            
    <div id="content"></div>
</form>
```

AJAX CALL

```
$("#send").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'servercode/contact.php',
        success: function(data){
            if(data != null) $("#content").html(data)
        }
    });
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['send'])){
    $to = 'abc@aol.com'; 
    $subject = 'Contact form website';

    $message = 'Name: ' . $_POST['miniusername'] . "\r\n\r\n"; 
    $message .= 'Email: ' . $_POST['miniemail'] . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= 'Message: ' . $_POST['message'];
    $success = mail($to, $subject, $message);
}?>
<?php if (isset($success) && $success) { ?>
    <h1>Thank You</h1>
    <p>Your message has been sent.</p>
<?php } else{ ?>
    <h1>Oops!</h1>
    <p>Sorry, there was a problem sending your message.</p>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Why are you using  multiple <?php ?>  tags in the PHP code??

Comment: When you click the send button, you will need to stop the default action. Use `preventDefault()` ...  http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: What's the php code rendering?

Comment: Im trying them all i guess lol to see what works

Comment: But all PHP code can be within one <?php ?> itself

Comment: There is more "wrong". Your PHP code is aimed at sending a form the default way. Also how are you picking up your form data?

Comment: The php is getting the values entered and sending them to my email, all works, now i want to output the result into the html div

Comment: You have a submit button ,it will submit the form,not perform the ajax call

Comment: its a kit called jkit that gets the data and sent it to the php

Comment: @Varun - There's absolutely nothing wrong with multiple PHP tags this way.  He's simply using it to break off the stdout.

Comment: then how do i output the result that i get from the php into the html div?

Comment: @webguy Make it a regular button and then the on click will work

Comment: I want to output lets say the Thank you to the div instead of showing the php file to the user

Comment: @JohnGreen Oh yes,Missed it.i am used to the habbit of echo(ing) everything

Comment: because the when you click send it goes to the php, i want that the php process on the background and it shows into the html without refreshing

Comment: wanted to echo to see if everything was working lol but i want the echo in the div and somehow it goes always into the php

Comment: Ok maybe i didnt make the question correctly, how do i output that thank you thing into the div instead of showing the php file to the user? with an example please :)

Answer (score 1):

You are not sending any data with your ajax call... Try doing it this way: Give your form an **ID (say, form_id)**

```
$("#form_id").submit(function(event)
{
 event.preventDefault();
 var data = $(this).serialize();
 var url = $(this).attr("action");
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    url: url,
    success: function(data){
             if(data != null) $("#content").html(data)
     },
    error: function(xhr,status,msg){
       console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you are not including any data on your post to the server, and you might want to explicitly specify the dataType parameter to indicate you expect HTML back.  There are several ways to accomplish this, but here is one:

```
$("#send").click(function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'servercode/contact.php',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: $(this).closest('form').serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      if (data) {
        $("#content").html(data);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

You might also want to review all the ajax options at: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

You may have another problem where the mail() command is not setup properly.  I've run into this issue where I have had to setup postfix and restart the webserver.

Comment: I did the ajax to try if i could get the thank you message into the div, the form is already sending data to php and php is sending the email which is good :) now im not sure how to output the thank you that is into the php into the div. I dont want the user to see my php page.. Do you know what i am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no way to interfere with jkit validate method (it provides no documented API) the only way I've managed it to work is to change the action attribute on form element to call javascript function instead of actually sending the form. To ensure that noscript users will be also able to use the form I've done that like this.

```
function sendContactForm() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: $("form").serialize(),
        url: 'servercode/contact.php',
        success: function(data){
            if(data != null) $("#content").html(data)
        }
    });

    return false;
};

$("form").prop("action", "javascript:sendContactForm()");
```

Also serialize() on form will not attach the <input type="submit" />'s value, so you need to slighly modify your PHP code:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST))
{
    $to = 'abc@aol.com'; 
    $subject = 'Contact form website';

    $message = 'Name: ' . $_POST['miniusername'] . "\r\n\r\n"; 
    $message .= 'Email: ' . $_POST['miniemail'] . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= 'Message: ' . $_POST['message'];
    $success = mail($to, $subject, $message);
} 

if (isset($success) && $success) { ?>
    <h1>Thank You</h1>
    <p>Your message has been sent.</p>
<?php } else { ?>
    <h1>Oops!</h1>
    <p>Sorry, there was a problem sending your message.</p>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: if i add the one you send, the validation and sending the values to the server doesnt work, maybe the ajax is conflicting with the validation jkit i have,
http://jquery-jkit.com/
 http://fredibach.ch/jquery-plugins/

Comment: Ok, I suspect that there is a event conflict, as validation jkit also want to handle submit event. You need to call your ajax function once validation is completed. I will update my answer to achieve that.

Comment: i dont get errors but the validation and passing of values to php dont work if i paste that ajax call, im not sure why.

Comment: Well, as validate method from jkit provides no callback api the only way I've found is to modify action attribute on form to javascript:sendTheForm(); It's ugly, but it works as long as javascript is enabled.

Comment: apparently works only in chrome, no ie firefox and safari...it returns false on the screen and on the pagename javascript:sendContact\form() anyone knows why? – @pamelus